# Exception was thrown while deserializing the token on CentOS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Why I got this exception ONLY in production environment (CentOS 7)?

> [ERR] An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
> antiforgery token could not be decrypted. --->
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
> {d41af177-dd3c-460d-8280-5f46d79ae0e3} was not found in the key ring

What's missing?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName(Security.Application_Name)
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new 
    DirectoryInfo(Security.Key_Path));
```

The file named key-dcee8f19-132e-4aff-84f0-7ef8c338533d.xml was created

to decrypt

```
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName(Security.Application_Name)
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Security.Key_Path));
    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var instance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Cipher>(services);
    string _mpid = instance.Decrypt(_xpid);
```

Comment: What version of Mono are you running on CentOS?

Comment: _"The key was not found in the key ring"_, so I guess it's not a program problem.